# There is no distribution certificate when i trying to create distribution profile using xcode

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store

I am developing an Ipad only application and i have problem with my code sign verification, i tried everything but nothing was working so i was trying to think what is wrong and when i try to create distribution provisioning profile using Xcode there was no distribution certificate showing there?

I am confuse because there was only development certificate but no distribution but i have crated the distribution certificate also and it is in my provisioning portal? can you tell me what's wrong, and as i know that for development and distribution certificate the process are same.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/79040977@N07/6959244884/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to download your Distribution certificate from the portal into your Keychain, and a distribution provision file from the portal into Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, but still i am not getting my answer why it is not showing into Xcode profile because i am getting the codesign verification error